# user roles and permission in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc application, where I have different roles of uses, and a role user have different functionality (ex: add, edit, delete,--), and  a user in each role will have sub set of this functionality in this role. I want to give permission to each user to view the pages based on this permissions.

What would be the best way to achieve this in mvc?

Thanks

Comment: You can implement a CustomMembershipProvider. By doing so, you can configure everything according to your needs. You can also use existing user tables in your database etc.

Comment: we are not using membership provider for some reason and we store these permission in the database itself and load when user login.

Comment: Well.. that sounds exactly like a CustomMembershipProvider mechanism in combination with a CustomRoleProvider ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In our application we have roles and each role has many functionalities. Our goal was to control access at the functionality level instead of role level using less access to the database as possible.

Here is what we do:

1) At the login, we create an UserCredentials object which contains all functionalities that the user has access (based on its roles). It is a "distinct" of all functionalities contained in all roles the user has access. Then we store this UserCredentials in session.

2) To restrict access to controllers or actions, we have implemented an attribute that inherits AuthorizeAttribute and we use like:

```
[Secure(Functionalities="Xyz.View,Xyz.Save")]
public ActionResult SomeAction(...){ ... }
```

Note that there is no database call, all we do is to check that "Xyz.View" is in the functionalities list stored in the UserCredentials.

3) Sometimes we need to access the credentials from inside the action, so we have created another ActionFilter (global) which will inject the credentials in the action parameters for you if he finds a parameter named "credentials", for instance:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(UserCredentials credentials, int otherParameters)
{
    // "credentials" is populated by the global action filter  
}
```

You could use this to show a different view based on the user Roles or Functionalities.

4) Another scenario is when we need to hide portions of our views based on user roles or functionalities. For this, we have created a BaseViewModel which has a UserCredentials property. This property is also populated by another global ActionFilter that runs AFTER the action is executed. If the model inherits BaseViewModel, then the filter populates UserCredentials property. We can do something like:

```
@if(Model.UserCredentials.IsInRole("X")){
    <div>Some content</div>
}
```

or

```
@if(Model.UserCredentials.HasAccessTo("Xyz.Save")){
    <button>Save</button>
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: `If the model inherits BaseViewModel...` Do you mean `if the **view model** inherits BaseViewModel`? Why would a model inherit from a view model?

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't completely sure myself so I was wondering if I was doing things wrong!